# how can i assign 2-dimensional array to datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview, multidimensional-array

i have 6 column in which the first column is a textboxcell and the rest are checkboxes.
and i want to put the value of two dimensional array to the datagrid.

```
string[,] debugger={{"name","0","0","1","1","0"}};
```

0=false
1=true (i assigned false value and true value from the datagridview property window.
when i try this it gives me a format exception ?

```
grdFont.ColumnCount=6;
            var row = new DataGridViewRow();
            row.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
            {
               Value = debugger[0] 
            });
            row.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell()
            {
                Value = debugger[1]
            });
            row.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell()
            {
                Value = debugger[2]
            });
            row.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell()
            {
                Value = debugger[3]
            });
            row.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell()
            {
                Value = debugger[4]
            });
            row.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell()
            {
                Value = debugger[5]
            });
            grdFont.Rows.Add(row);
```

is there another way i can implement this?

Comment: This may help :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111308/2-dimensional-integer-array-to-datagridview

Comment: why are you using debugger[1],[2] etc? do it in a loop

Comment: because am on feasibility study not actual application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0 is not equvalent of `false` and 1 is not equivalent of `true`. Write a function to convert these numbers to `Boolean` value:

```
public bool ConvertNumberToBoolean(int number)
{
    if (number == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Use this function when you set a value to cell:

```
row.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell()
{
    Value = ConvertNumberToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(debugger[1]));
});
```

It's a pretty basic realization, but I believe you got the idea

Comment: ya i know but what is (FalseValue and TrueValue) property for inside visual studio? [link] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcolumn.falsevalue.aspx