# How do I show the contents of this array using DataGridView?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I created a 2 dimensional array of strings and populated it.  I try to bind it to a DataGrid control like so:

```
string[][] Array = new string[100][];
dataGridView.DataSource = Array;
```

Instead of seeing the contents of the array I see the following columns: Length, LongLenth, Rank, SyncRoot, IsReadOnly, IsFixedSize, IsSyncrhonized.

So instead of displaying the contents of my array, it displays the properties of the array.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: how do you expect to see that information into the GV?

Comment: What does your XAML look like for your DataGrid control?

Comment: For [x][y] I was hoping each row would represent the [X]...and columns would represent the [Y], so that the contents of [2][5] would be displayed on the Datagrid in the 2nd row, 5 column.

Comment: @ryrich What is XAML?

Comment: For starters, I wouldn't call your array "Array." Besides that, run this through the debugger and after you've defined your Array, look at it in a Watch window. See if you can identify the property that will give you what you're looking for.

Comment: You cannot bind directly a jagged array to a datagridview. However you can display it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111308/2-dimensional-integer-array-to-datagridview

Comment: @ryrich `DataGridView` not `DataGrid`, I expect he's using WinForms not WPF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you allow the grid control to auto-generate columns, it will basically enumerate through the properties of that object and create a column for each one.  It has no way to know that you want to display this as a grid of array values.

You'll need to create a new object (such as an enumerable list of a class) out of the array with the properties you want to bind to as columns.  A quick way to do this would be to use an anonymous type, built using a LINQ query.  Something like:

```
string[][] Array = new string[100][];
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) // Set some values to test
   Array[i] = new string[2] { "Value 1", "Value 2" };

dataGridView.DataSource = (from arr in Array select new { Col1 = arr[0], Col2 = arr[1] });
Page.DataBind();
```

Here, we're iterating through all 100 elements of the array.  Each element is an array of 2 strings.  We're creating an anonymous type out of those two strings.  This type has two properties: `Col1` and `Col2`.  `Col1` will be set to array index 0, and `Col2` will be set to array index 1.  Then, we're building the grid to that enumeration of anonymous types.  This will look something like:

[image]

You can of course define exactly how columns will be created by setting `AutoGenerateColumns` to False, and populated the `Columns` collection.  This can be done declaratively as well within your ASPX file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your array to a datatable

```
string[][] Array = new string[100][];
DataTable dt= new DataTable();

int l= Array.length;

for(int i=0;i<l;i++) {
     dt.LoadDataRow(Array[i], true); //Pass array object to LoadDataRow method
}

dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
string[][] Array = new string[100][];

ArrayList arrList = new ArrayList();
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    arrList.Add(new ListItem(Array[i, 0], Array[i, 1]));
}
Grid2D.DataSource = arrList;
Grid2D.DataBind();
```

See this link [**Binding Arrays to GridView in ASP.Net**](http://www.aspsnippets.com/articles/binding-arrays-to-gridview-in-asp.net.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
using Linq;

var Found = (from arr in myArray2D select 
new { row1 = arr[0], row2 = arr[1], row3 = arr[2] })
.Where(y => (y.row1.ToUpper() + y.row2.ToUpper())
.Contains(sText.ToUpper()))
.OrderByDescending(y => Convert.ToInt32(y.row3)).ToList();
dataGridViewFind.DataSource = Found;
dataGridViewFind.AutoResizeColumns();
```

Comment: These commands search for a text in columns 1 and 2 of the array and return by bringing columns 1, 2, and 3 of the array and sorting them down by column 3 converted from string to number.