# Display a fixed-length 2D-Array on the GUI

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to display a fixed-length 2D Array without having all the array items in 100 variables and binding each variable to the UI?

I have an array (for example of pictures) and want to show it exactly as it is (4x3 array):

```
x x x x
x x x x
x x x x
```

Comment: See [My Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15344546/643085) of such a thing in WPF.

Answer (score -1):

check out following post, you can use datagridview to display dynamically the 2d arrays:

[2-dimensional Integer array to DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111308/2-dimensional-integer-array-to-datagridview)

Using datagridview you can add custom number of rows and columns. It is specially for c# where you can easily use datagridview for dynamic displaying...

Comment: -1 an answer with just a link is not appropriate in StackOverflow.

Comment: Further more it's a win forms solution.