# Is there a way to open silent/invisible a new form and screenshot it?

Tags: c#, winforms

At the moment I open automatically a new form, loading a chart, make a screenshot only in RAM and sending it to my private chat in telegram. All good so far, but is there a way, to open the form silent (also not shown and not focusing / invisible) and screenshot the silent form?

This is atm my code and working fine but without a silent function. anyone can help me?

```
_f2 = new Form2();
_f2.Show();

while(true)
{
    if(Form2Closed == true)
    {
        Form2Closed = false;
        break;
    }
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

```
// loading chart stuff

var frm = Form2.ActiveForm;
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var bmp = new Bitmap(frm.Width, frm.Height))
    {
        frm.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
        bmp.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);// "screenshot.png");
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        bmp.Dispose();
        // sending stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Unclear which technology this is meant to be. WPF? WebForms? WinForms? Modern UI? Something different?

Comment: (a) don't call `Show`.  (b) you won't be able to use `ActiveForm`, because an invisible window can't be active.  But that isn't a problem because you already have a reference to the form object.

Comment: @UweKeim: The combination of `Form` and `DrawToBitmap` points to WinForms.

Comment: @UweKeim I did not know that this is important, sorry... Actually this is WinForms (Net..)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798971/displaying-a-2d-data-array-from-a-console-application/33414809#33414809) may be helpful

Comment: Side note: because `bmp` is wrapped in a `using` block, you don't need to call `.Dispose()` because `using` takes care of that for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the form invisible by setting its `Opacity` property to 0:

```
var frm = new Form2();
frm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
frm.Opacity = 0;
frm.Show();

using (var bmp = new Bitmap(frm.Width, frm.Height))
{
    frm.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
    // Do something with the bitmap.
}
```

The `DrawToBitmap` method should work just fine even while the form is hidden.

Note that it would also work if you set the `Visible` property to `false` (e.g., by calling `frm.Hide();`) right after showing the form, but that would cause the form to appear for a split second. Setting `Opacity` to 0 *before calling `Show()`* ensures that the form is invisible from the get-go. Alternatively, you could override `SetVisibleCore` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3742980/8967612).

Comment: Don't call `Show()` at all if you don't want it to become visible.

Comment: @BenVoigt Not calling `Show()` will cause `CreateHandle()` to not be called and controls on the form won't be displayed properly, if at all. That's why when overriding `SetVisibleCore`, it's important to call `CreateHandle()` yourself as shown in the linked answer.

Answer (score 0):

check this thread:
[How to take a screenshot of a WPF control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466482/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-wpf-control/24478299#24478299)

`RenderTargetBitmap.Render` should works with minimalised window :).